# zend framework - creating controller for admin/action1/action2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

In zend framework, how do i create an action for this type of url:

```
example.com/admin/create/category
```

which would show a page for creating a new category

or

```
example.com/admin/edit/category/id
```

which would show a page to edit a category

here, admin would be the `controller`, create and edit would be the `action` but what about the last parameter 'category'? should i check for 'category' argument inside the controller actions or is there another way ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having this kind of issue, I suggest using zend route. Here's the link

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

You can create multiple routes for each action if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the good way is to check for 'category' argument inside the controller actions. Based on its value you do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have lots of different "things" you need to administer then i woudl suggest not using ana single `admin` controller but rather a `Category` controller. Then just secure the admin actions. Alternatively you sould have 2 controllers a Category controller and an AdminCategory controller...But either way you should have multiple controllers for the admin module....

Also keep in mind you can set up routes pretty much however you like... not every segment in the url needs to map to a parameter...

Comment: yes, securing admin actions is a great idea.will certainly look into it.